# Visual Studio like collapsible, hidable and dockable windows in mvc4

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

Visual Studio 2012 like collapsible, hidable and dockable windows in mvc4 website...

Are they possibe? Any help to get me started around this would be much appreciated. I am using VS2012.

Need to create a website in MVC4 similar to webparts, but seems it ain't a straight forward task..Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy plugin out there to behave in exact same way, but with some widgets that javascript libraries like jquery UI or Kendo UI offers and writing some jquery and css on your own you can do that.  look at these to get some ideas :

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/splitter/index.html

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/